# Is this possible to give different links for the same wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, permalinks

I have developed a site using wordpress. I have two main links in the site e.g. **www.mysite.com/siteone** and **www.mysite.com/sitetwo** and I have managed only one blog contents. Now what I need to do is that I want to link the same blog with different link like this:
**www.mysite.com/siteone/blog** and **www.mysite.com/sitetwo/blog** and also need to have same content for links **www.mysite.com/siteone/blog-1** and **www.mysite.com/sitetwo/blog-1**. Is it possible to do so, if yes then how to do that? If not then what can I do for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the SEO perspective, it's wise to use canonical tag. This tag was a new construct designed explicitly for purposes of identifying and
dealing with duplicate content. Implementation is very simple and looks like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.yoursite.org/blog" />
```

This tag is meant to tell Yahoo!, Bing, and Google that the page in question should be treated
as though it were a copy of the URL http://www.yoursite.org/blog and that all of the link and
content metrics the engines apply should technically flow back to that URL.
The canonical URL tag attribute is similar in many ways to a 301 redirect from an SEO
perspective. In essence, you’re telling the engines that multiple pages should be considered as
one (which a 301 does), without actually redirecting visitors to the new URL (often saving
your development staff trouble).

[link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://www.amazon.com/Art-SEO-Theory-Practice/dp/0596518862&rct=j&q=the%20art%20of%20seo&ei=3dyvTfOvF4-LswaOp8DkCw&usg=AFQjCNG40N8ozqOzl6ThSgEQD8DZuDjopw&sig2=QTHR-Zy_qVqnYqd8t9UWbg&cad=rja)

Answer (score 0):

The "home" link in a WordPress installation is determined by an option in the database called `siteurl`, so in theory you'll just have to use the same database on both blogs and override the `siteurl` on the two to make it seem like two different websites.

A good way to start from is define a constant in your wp-config.php, which should be different for both websites:

```
define( 'MY_SITE_URL', 'http://yoursite.com/siteone/blog' );
```

And then write a single-line plugin that would simply add a filter to the `get_option` call for `siteurl`. Something like this:

```
add_filter( 'option_siteurl', create_function( '$value', 'return MY_SITE_URL;' ) );
```

That's only the start, and if that works for you you'll have to then rumble around your wp-content directory to make sure they are in sync for both websites, i.e. after uploading an image to one blog you'll need to copy the file into the other one.

I did manage to get two different websites working under one WordPress installation using two different databases, but having two WordPress installations working line one site under two different domains, that's tricky ;)

~ K